# Why can't I get any website to accept my CONNECT request?

Tags: python, http, tcp, proxy, request

I cannot get any website to accept my CONNECT request. I was trying to create a simple forward proxy server but how come I can't even get to make CONNECT work? If websites actually don't allow CONNECT (like, httpbin doesn't) then death to all HTTP proxies I guess?

As seen on https://reqbin.com/Article/HttpConnect I tried to do a CONNECT request and miserably failed...

```py
def test4():
    # https://reqbin.com/Article/HttpConnect
    url = r"https://reqbin.com:443"
    headers = {
        "Host": "reqbin.com:443"
        }

    with httpx.Client() as client:
        response = client.request("CONNECT", url, headers=headers)
        print(response,response.text)
```

The print outputted a whole HTML page so I will only tell the relevant parts:

- `<Response [400 Bad Request]>`
- `<title>HTTP CONNECT is not supported | reqbin.com | Cloudflare</title>`

So like, what? Does that literally mean CONNECT is not allowed so death to all HTTP proxies? Is CONNECT deprecated? What happened? I don't get it...
I want to create a proxy server but I am literally trying websites to accept CONNECT requests right now... Why is this even an issue? Not only with reqbin, google also gives me a HTTP 400 with "malformed request" and httpbin literally says "method not supported".

I also tried a socket approach. You can see it below if you want to I guess...

```py
def test5():
    import socket
    # Useless, almost same as test4 actually... HTTP 400 by cloudflare.
    import socket
    target_host = "reqbin.com"
    target_port = 443

    # Create a socket connection to the target server
    with socket.create_connection((target_host, target_port)) as sock:
        # Send the raw CONNECT request taken from https://reqbin.com/Article/HttpConnect exactly
        connect_request = f"CONNECT {target_host}:{target_port} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {target_host}:{target_port}\r\n\r\n"
        sock.sendall(connect_request.encode())

        # Receive and print the response
        response = sock.recv(4096)
        print(response.decode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CONNECT request is done from the client to the forward proxy in order to establish a connection to the target by the proxy. Within this connection the HTTPS traffic from the client is then forwarded to the target and the response traffic back, without additional encapsulation by a new CONNECT request to the target site.

Thus CONNECT is only relevant between client and forward proxy. Since arbitrary websites are not forward proxies they don't support the CONNECT request.

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions from this though, first one is: is there a dummy http proxy website where i can test CONNECT? Reqbin, despite even putting the example themselves, didn’t accept CONNECT and some random proxy I picked up from proxy scraper all timed out… | Second: When the proxy gets CONNECT request, how should it handle that? Reply with 200 to client while creating a socket with target server? And then what exactly?  A socket with client for tcp data too? Like, 2 sockets? I am not sure how that part will be like.

Comment: @Hiello: First: don't know of any existing test server, but there is open source proxy software like squid which can be used to setup your own test setup. Second: after the proxy got the CONNECT request it will establish a new (second) TCP connection to the target server given in the CONNECT request. Once this TCP connection got established successfully it will reply with success (code 200) to the client. After that it will transfer data between client and server in both directions until one of the TCP connections got closed by the peer.

Comment: Oh okay. So, I am sorry for my lack of knowledge but how will the client send data from the point it receives status code 200? Like, it now has to send TCP packets to the proxy server I guess, which is pretty low level. Do I need to like, get to the socket used for communicating with the client and start listening to it manually… I guess I will need to find an example at this point. Thank you again.

Comment: @Hiello: The client simply continues to use the established TCP socket to the proxy. The difference between HTTPS traffic without proxy and HTTPS traffic with a HTTP proxy is basically the additional CONNECT request handshake at the start of the TCP communication.

Comment: Thank you again. Is there a way to know if the last TCP packet arrived when the time comes before delivering that last TCP packet to the other party (from server to client)? I am trying to block a certain URL with an endpoint but I cannot know the endpoint because it is also encrypted. The only thing is that this endpoint always send the same file. So I thought, the encrypted total size of bytes received from server shouldn’t change either(?) and could be a way to identify if this is the URL I want to block.

Comment: @Hiello: What is going on inside the HTTPS connection is transparent to the proxy. There is no indication of a last byte - there is only indication of TCP connection close. And there might be multiple requests and responses (i.e. downloads) over the same connection. So what you are trying to achieve is not possible with a simple proxy.